# How to update a single firebase firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After authenticating i'm trying to lookup a user document at /users/, then i'd like to update the document with data from auth object as well some custom user properties.  But I'm getting an error that the update method doesn't exist.  Is there a way to update a single document?  All the firestore doc examples assume you have the actual doc id, and they don't have any examples querying with a where clause.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("uid", "==", payload.uid)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          doc.update({foo: "bar"})
      });
 })
```

Comment: Why not use the `uid` as the actual document ID when storing the data? That makes this problem much simpler.

Comment: Now that is a damn good idea.  That is the solution.  Since everything in a typical app's database will have content tied to a specific user, which  is common many relational db designs.  I'd recommend a doc or tutorial on this for firebase/firestore.  Creating a separate /users collection, and  keeping it in sync with the firebase Auth users was not that intuitive.

Comment: I think the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714423/firestore-query-then-update is what you're looking for

Answer (score 125):

You can precisely do as follows (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference):

```
// firebase v8
var db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update({foo: "bar"});

//firebase v9
const db = getFirestore();
async (e) => { //...
 await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", doc.id), {
    foo: 'bar'
  });
//....
```

check out the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) as well

Comment: why did you need to do a get request if you already had the uid?
didnt we just need that one line `          db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update({foo: "bar"});`

Comment: Does `db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update({foo: "bar"})` count as both a read and a write? In the example above would it have been more cost effective to just do `doc.ref.update({foo: "bar"})`?

Comment: We need a get request because `uid != doc.id`. For example, you may have used an automatically assigned doc id.

Comment: @themanatuf , `db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update({foo: "bar"})` and `doc.ref.update({foo: "bar"})` should both count as a single write. You're right that `doc.ref` is better, though. Updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: how can we use where condition on document then update then document fields? Kindly share any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

**-- UPDATE FOR FIREBASE V9 --**

In the newer version of Firebase this is done like this:

```
import { doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const washingtonRef = doc(db, "cities", "DC");

// Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
  capital: true
});
```

Comment: where I get lost even now on this is, what uniquely identifies the document..
Is it something that happens behind the scenes in firebase.

Comment: In this case "DC" is the unique identifier of the document. @Juice

Answer (score 26):

Check if the user is already there then simply `.update`,  or `.set` if not:

```
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    var o = {};
    docRef.get().then(function(thisDoc) {
        if (thisDoc.exists) {
            //user is already there, write only last login
            o.lastLoginDate = Date.now();
            docRef.update(o);
        }
        else {
            //new user
            o.displayName = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
            o.accountCreatedDate = Date.now();
            o.lastLoginDate = Date.now();
            // Send it
            docRef.set(o);
        }
        toast("Welcome " + firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    toast(error.message);
});
```

Comment: no reason to do all of that, since set will automatically update if the record isn't there:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data
"If the document does not exist, it will be created. If the document does exist, its contents will be overwritten with the newly provided data, unless you specify that the data should be merged into the existing document, as follows:"

Comment: that is for the `.set` method. Unless something has changed, `.update` will fail if the doc does not already exist (unlike realtime database where `.update` will create it for you if it does not exist.

Comment: Will update still fail today if the doc doesn't exist?

Answer (score 19):

in your original code changing this line

```
doc.update({foo: "bar"})
```

to this

```
doc.ref.update({foo: "bar"})
```

should work

but a better way is to use batch write:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Answer (score 2):

correct way to do this is as follows;
to do any data manipulation in snapshot object we have to reference the .ref
attribute

```
 firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("uid", "==", payload.uid)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          doc.ref.update({foo: "bar"})//not doc.update({foo: "bar"})
      });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to found official ID of document, code here!

```
    enter code here
    //Get user mail (logined)
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
    val mail = user?.email.toString()

       //do update
       val update = db.collection("spending").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                val doc = snapshot?.documents
                doc?.forEach {
                    //Assign data that I got from document (I neet to declare dataclass) 
                    val spendData= it.toObject(SpendDt::class.java)
                    if (spendData?.mail == mail) {
                        //Get document ID
                        val userId = it.id
                        //Select collection
                        val sfDocRef = db.collection("spendDocument").document(userId)
                        //Do transaction
                        db.runTransaction { transaction ->
                            val despesaConsum = hashMapOf(
                                "medalHalfYear" to true,
                            )
                            //SetOption.merege() is for an existing document
                            transaction.set(sfDocRef, despesaConsum, SetOptions.merge())
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
}
data class SpendDt(
    var oilMoney: Map<String, Double> = mapOf(),
    var mail: String = "",
    var medalHalfYear: Boolean = false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to these answers: if you don't have access to `doc` and are looking to get the document **dynamically**.

Sadly, in `React Native` environment, I couldn't find a way to import `doc`, to get the `id`. I'm working with https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage. It can be the same case for some less common environments relying on `Firebase` plugin/libraries.

In that case `console.log(documentSnapshot.ref);` will return you what you can find below.

[image]

as you could see, while working with the `raw` response, it can be accessed via `documentSnapshot.ref._documentPath._parts[1]`. `documentSnapshot` is of course part of `querySnapshot`. In the question, it's referred as `doc`.

Now you can pass it to the call:

```js
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"; // you could have it imported from a different library, but always better to just import firestore rather than entire firebase from which you can (also) get firestore.
...
firestore()
  .collection(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME)
  .doc(documentSnapshot.ref._documentPath._parts[1]) // or assign it to a variable, and then use - better
  .update({...})
  .then(() => {})
  .catch(() => {})
  .finally(() => {});
```