# How to dynamically update a document in a collection within Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been able to dynamically create records (user profiles) and retrieve their unique ID in Firebase.

But now I want the ability to have an end user update their profile. While I can retrieve the document ID aka uid of the profile. How do I template out the ability to dynamically fetch the uid of the person signed in and update that specific record?

I have tried the following:

```
 async updateProfile() {
    const docRef = await db.collection("users").get(`${this.userId}`);
    docRef.update({
      optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
      phone: this.form.mobile
    });
    db.collection("users")
      .update({
        optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
        phone: this.form.mobile
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Profile successfully updated!");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
  }
```

`

I've also tried

```
 async updateProfile() {
    const docRef = await db.collection("users").where("userId", "==", `${this.userId}`);
    docRef.update({
      optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
      phone: this.form.mobile
    });
    db.collection("users")
      .update({
        optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
        phone: this.form.mobile
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Profile successfully updated!");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
  }
```

``

And this

```
  async updateProfile() {
    const docRef = await db.collection("users").get(`${this.userId}`);
    docRef.update({
      optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
      phone: this.form.mobile
    });
    db.collection("users/`${this.userId}`")
      .update({
        optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
        phone: this.form.mobile
      })
      .then(function () {
        console.log("Profile successfully updated!");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
      });
  }
```

Error `docRef.update is not a function`

Comment: get() doesn't return a document reference.  It returns a document snapshot.  I think you might be helped by reviewing the samples in the documentation to better understand how get() works.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, after reviewing this post: [How to update a single firebase firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682327/how-to-update-a-single-firebase-firestore-document).

The collection I am trying to reference is a user table with data created from Firebase's out of the box Google auth. So querying and updating the data was different than my other data where the doc ID is equal to the uid of the collection. Working solution:

```
  async updateProfile() {

    const e164 = this.concatenateToE164();

    const data = {
      optInTexts: this.form.optInTexts,
      phone: e164};

    const user = await db.collection('users')
      .where("uid", "==", this.userId)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update(data);
        });
      })
  }
```