# Firestore - Query, then update

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return an item with a specific ID and perform an update operation on it. My query gets the right result, but it won't let me update it.

I tried following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYyPbfpoZeM
And read the documentation. Both didn't help. Other threads to the same topic are, well, different.

I have a database of objects which have a unique ID stored as integer.
I have an HTML form to get an ID as user input and the query below to retrieve the according object.

I tried this. The query worked, the update didn't.

```
db.collection('objects').where('ID','==', ID ).get().then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach( doc => {
            console.log('debug');
            console.log(doc.data().ID);
        })
    });
```

I am still new to firebase and js, so please forgive me if my code is uterly wrong.
I am currently stuck with this:

```
db.collection('objects').where('ID','==', ID ).get().then((doc) => {
    console.table(doc);
});
```

Which is still not working.

For the second snippet an I currently get an unlegible table in which I can't really find the object I was looking for.

How do I update a single value in a single document?

EDIT: I forgot my implementation  attempts of the update function.
I tried `doc.update({value:0})` inside the for loop in snippet one which yielded `doc.update is not a function`. Similarly for `doc.data().update(...)`.

In the second snippet I mainly tried to see what I got returned and ran variations of the above mentioned uodate function. With no success.

Comment: where is your update code ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta edited, thanks for pointing out I missed my main point

Comment: are you using AngularFirestore `AngularFirestore` ? And do you know to do anything inside that loop aside from updating the value ?

Comment: AngularFirebase, not that I know. I don't know what it would mean. Do I _know_ to do anything inside the loop? I don't want to do anything else in the loop. For now only console logging for debugging.

Comment: Can I see your constructor ?

Comment: In my mind a constructor belongs to object oriented programming, right? I don't know what you mean with regards to non-OO js.

Comment: Ok I added an answer try it

Comment: did that work for you ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta No, added comments about why

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by studying the part of the firestore documentation that goes more into detail about the actual functions. Somehow it was hard for me to find this.

```
db.collection("users").where("name", "==", somename).limit(1).get().then(query => {
                console.log(query);
                const thing = query.docs[0];
                console.log(thing.data());
                let tmp = thing.data();
                tmp.current_game_play = tmp.current_game_play + 1;
                console.log(tmp);
                thing.ref.update(tmp);
            });
```

So I use `where` to get a Query object, use `get` to get a a querySnapshot inside the `then` promise resolve, use `docs[0]` to retrieve the first (and only) documentSnapshot and finally `ref` to get a reference that makes the whole thing *updatable* later.

Comment: link to the docs that talks about the `ref` of the `querysnapshotdocument` https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var objectRef= db.collection("objects").doc(ID);

objectRef.update({
    value: 0
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    // The document probably doesn't exist.
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
});
```

Comment: Either I do `const ID = parseInt(userInput);` and get `argument must be of type string but is int` or I do it without parseInt and it doesn't return any objects

Comment: Also, I need the new `value` to be based on the old value, how would I do that? Can I simply say `.update({value: value-othervalue})`?

Comment: @Harri think the problem is your userInput, what are you expecting from the user? and how do your firestoreI Ids look like ?

Comment: user input is originally a string. I can easily cast it to int. Within firestore IDs are ints. Alternatively, is there an easy way to retrieve the IDs generated by firestore?