# How to edit a document in Google-Cloud-Firestore by using a function in an Angular Service

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `google-cloud-firestore` as the database of my project. I have a collection named `Manufacture` and it contains documents named `manufacture` It is in following capture.

[image]

I added data for this by manually. But however now I want to edit data by using a function in service. Think if I want to change address from `melborn` to `japan` of the collection which belonging to `nic=0011`, How I do this. I have a angular service named `finished.service.ts` and it is containing a funciton named `editDatabase()` what is for edit the database. Can you help me to implement this function.

**finished.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Finished } from './finished.model';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FinishedService {

    patients_for_dialog: Finished;

    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

    editDatabase(){

    }
}
```

In this I should mention about `Finished` model. you can see it in below.

**finished.model.ts**

```
export class Finished {

    address: string;
    contactno: string;
    nic: string;

}
```

How I implement this.

```
editDatabase(){

}
```

Comment: [**check this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49682615/3937794)

Comment: I tried for this, But could not found a solution yet.