# Passing data from Formik onSubmit to Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, formik

I'm trying to connect Formik to send updated form data to Firestore to build an "edit" screen of sorts.

I've got my form and fields set up with Formik, and can load the current data from Firebase in as initial field values fine. I'm stuck on sending updated data from Formik's onSubmit() to my updateVessel().

Here's my code:

```
const VesselEditScreen = props => {

    const vesselId = props.route.params.vesselId;
    const vesselName = props.route.params.vesselName;

    // ===================================================================================
    // Set up Firebase

    // Set db location
    const ref = db.collection('vessels');

    // Set up state
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [vesselData, setVesselData] = useState();

    // Handle load data
    useEffect(() => {
        return ref.doc(vesselId).onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {

            const vessel = documentSnapshot.data();
            setVesselData(vessel);

            if (loading) {
                setLoading(false);
            }

        });
    }, []);

    // Handle update data
    async function updateVessel() {
        await ref.doc(vesselId).update({
            // Not sure here?
        });
    }

    // ===================================================================================
    // Check if we're loading/saving data

    if (loading) {
        return <LoadingSpinner />
    };

    // ===================================================================================
    // Render form

    return (
        <ScreenWrapper>

            <StandardBox>

                <HeadingOne>Edit {vesselName}</HeadingOne>

                <Formik
                    initialValues={{
                        name: vesselData.name,
                        breadth: vesselData.breadth,
                        callsign: vesselData.callsign
                    }}
                    onSubmit={values => {
                        const { name, breadth, callsign } = values;
                        updateVessel();
                    }}
                >
                    {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                    <View>

                        <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange('name')} onBlur={handleBlur('name')} value={values.name} />
                        <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange('breadth')} onBlur={handleBlur('breadth')} value={values.breadth} />
                        <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange('callsign')} onBlur={handleBlur('callsign')} value={values.callsign} />

                        <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />

                    </View>
                    )}
                </Formik>

            </StandardBox>

        </ScreenWrapper>
    );

};

export default VesselEditScreen;
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the values of `onSubmit` to your function that will update the firebase

```
onSubmit={values => {
    const { name, breadth, callsign } = values;
    // passing the values you want
    updateVessel({ name, breadth, callsign });
}}
```

And then pass it to `update`

```
async function updateVessel(values) {
    await ref.doc(vesselId).update(values);
}
```

And in case you aren't sure how to update a single document, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682327/how-to-update-a-single-firebase-firestore-document) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following function to remove empty/null values which were blocking the firebase save:

```
const removeEmpty = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => (obj[key] == null) && delete obj[key]);
    return obj;
}
```

And called it in my Formik onSubmit like this:

```
onSubmit={values => {
    updateVessel( removeEmpty(values) );
}}
```

Then my function to update the vessel in Firebase:

```
async function updateVessel(values) {
    await ref.doc(vesselId).update(values);
    props.navigation.navigate('DashboardScreen');
}
```