# More direct method for updating fields in Firebase document without document ID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The goal is to update a Firebase document.

The document ID is unknown at the time of updating. What is known is a property that acts as unique key on the document (email address in the case below).

Based on [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682327/how-to-update-a-single-firebase-firestore-document), the code below works as a method for updating an array within the document.

This feels clunky, though.

Are there more direct methods for retrieving a reference to a single document and updating its fields?

```
    // Set query.
    let query = firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('emailAddress', '==', 'test@test.com');

    // Run query.
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await query.get();
    return querySnapshot.docs[0].ref.update({
        designs: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('foobar')
    })

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error getting user: ', e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you're doing is the best you can do.  If you don't know the ID, you have to query to find it.  Firestore has no equivalent of a SQL "update where" command.