# Firestore update collection value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello here is my code:

```
const selectedWeek = selectBoxWeek.options[selectBoxWeek.selectedIndex].value;
const selectedStudent = selectBoxAttStud.options[selectBoxAttStud.selectedIndex].value;

const selectuser = await db.collection('Presence').where('UserId', '==', selectedStudent).get();
const getA= selectuser.docs.map(doc=>doc.id);   

db.collection('presence').doc(getA[0]).update({
    selectedWeek: 1
});
```

In the selectedWeek variable, I get the week I want to update (week1,week2,week3,week4).

The document includes : week1,week2,week3,week4

But I get this error:  *Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update:*
Because selectedWeek does not exist in the document.

How can I solve this, to update the correct week value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a single firebase firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682327/how-to-update-a-single-firebase-firestore-document)

Comment: If it did not solve your question consider that the error message states that there is infact no document named selectedWeek perhahps you need to create it first before updating it. Aslo perhaps you meant to do: `db.collection('presence').doc(getA[0]).update({
    'selectedWeek': selectedWeek
});`

Comment: Other than the link shared on how to update a document, you may want to start by ensuring the document is named correctly...

is it "Presence" or "presence"?

Answer (score 0):

You can precisely do as follows (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref):

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("users").doc(doc.id).update({foo: "bar"});
```