# I want edit data in firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to edit data in firebase database.

But on my syntax I don't get right answer. Can you help me.

```
 const addNewData = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let data = {
  sifra:sifraRef.current.value,
  naziv:nazivRef.current.value,
  detalji_dijete:detaljiRef.current.value,
  opis:opisRef.current.value,
  broj_obroka:brojObrokaRef.current.value,
  napomena:napomenaRef.current.value
}  
const uuid = uid();
await updateDoc(collection(db, `namirnice/${uuid}`), data)


  close();

  }
```

I changed my syntax but I get this answer in console.
BTW all these ways are from youtube tutorials.

But my console.log right now is:Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but namirnice/5b61b327e2e has 2.

Comment: The `collection(db..)` should be `doc(db, ..)` in the `updateDoc()` Can you please edit your question and add code as text so it's easier for us to copy and edit it?

Comment: I changed to doc but I now get this message from console.
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but namirnice/f79db22da55 has 2.

Edit: This is same database like in previous post

Comment: `await addDoc(collection(db, 'namirnice'), data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `updateDoc` 
 [Firestore updateDoc documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437913/7481663)

FYI, if you dont know, collections and documents are different. Difference in references :

```
const alovelaceDocumentRef = doc(db, 'users', 'alovelace'); //even number of segments
const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users'); //odd number of segments
```

Other differences discussed in [Firestore data model documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#references).

Comment: I still don't get, how to edit data.

Comment: @Dragan , you accepted the answer, did you get it?

Comment: Yes, I get it. I figure out how i need to sent data id (third argument).